# How do I keep mongo's array index from changing during an update?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, indexing

I am trying to update an array within my object.  However, every time I send the post call, the index in the array changes.

I have tried using $set and manually updating the array... but the index on the array keeps changing.

Here is the model:

```
const MappedImageSchema = new Schema({
    imageUrl: {type: String, required: true},
    name: {type: String, required: true},
    areas:[
        {
            name: {type: String},
            shape: {type: String},
            coords:[{type: Number}],
        }
    ]
});
module.exports = MappedImage = mongoose.model('mappedImages', MappedImageSchema)
```

Here is the code that performs the update:

```
// @route   POST api/maps/:id/areas
// @desc    add an area to a map (by map id)
// @access  Private
router.post('/:id/areas/:id_area', passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }),
    (req, res) => {

        MappedImage.findById(req.params.id)
        .then(map => {

            // get all of the areas from the map...
            var allAreas = map.areas;

            // now get the index of the area we are going to update
            const areaIndex = map.areas.map(item => item._id.toString()).indexOf(req.params.id_area);

            // update the information
            var coords = req.body.coords.split(',');
            const updatedArea = {
                name: req.body.name,
                shape: req.body.shape,

                coords: coords,
            };

            // set the updated information in the correct map area
            allAreas[areaIndex] = updatedArea;

            var query = {_id: req.params.id}; // this is the MAP id
            var update = {$set: {areas:allAreas}};  // update the areas 
            var options = {new: true};

            MappedImage.findOneAndUpdate(query, update, options)
            .then(map => res.json(map))
            .catch(err => res.status(404).json({ mapnotfound: err }));

        })
        .catch(err => res.status(404).json({ mapnotfound: 'Map not found while updating area' }));
    }
  );
```

Here is the data BEFORE the call

```
{
    "_id": "5c5c69dda40e872258b4531d",
    "imageUrl": "url test",
    "name": "name test",
    "areas": [
        {
        "coords": [1,2,3,4,5,6],
        "_id": "5c5c8db2f904932dd8d4c560",  <---- _id changes every time !
        "name": "area name",
        "shape": "poly"
        }
    ],
    "__v": 3
}
```

Here is the Postman call I make:

[image]

The result of the call is the name gets changed... but so does the index... making the next call fail with "no area found with that index".

[image]

What is perplexing about this problem is the _id for the map does not get updated when I run this code:

```
router.post('/:id', passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }),
(req, res) => {

    var query = {_id: req.params.id};
    var update = {imageUrl: req.body.imageUrl, name: req.body.name};
    var options = {new: true};

    MappedImage.findOneAndUpdate(query, update, options)
    .then(map => res.json(map))
    .catch(err => res.status(404).json({ mapnotfound: err }));
});
```

**Update 1**

I tried using the areas index and updating just that area... but the _id changes with this code as well:

```
        ... same code all the way down to here
        allAreas[areaIndex] = updatedArea;

        // but instead of calling 'findOneAndUpdate'... call map save
        map.save().then(map => res.json(map));
```

**Update 2**

I can't get this code to work as areas._id and areas.$ are undefined ?

```
var query = {_id: req.params.id, areas._id: id_area}; // this is the MAP id
var update = {$set: {areas.$: updatedArea}};  // update the area
```

**Update 3**

So, putting the _id in the updatedArea fixes this issue... but it "feels" wrong to do so:  ( per eol answer )

```
        const updatedArea = {
            _id: req.params.id_area,
            name: req.body.name,
            shape: req.body.shape,

            coords: coords,
        };
```

**Update 4**

eol - thanks for the verification on the mongoDB side... If that solves the DB id problem... I just need to know why my query is failing.  I tried this and all I see in the terminal output is "creating query"... I never see the "query" and it's definition... so something is wrong and I don't know how to figure out what.  Here is what I have now:

```
 console.log('creating query');
 var query = {"_id": req.params.id, "areas._id": id_area};
 console.log('query');
 console.log(query);
```

**Update 5**
Figured it out why the query not being output, id_area is not defined... but req.params.id_area is !

```
 console.log('creating query');
 var query = {"_id": req.params.id, "areas._id": req.params.id_area};
 console.log('query');
```

**Update 6**

Code is in... but it is still not working. A picture is worth a 1000 words... so here are two:

This one shows the areas ID is still changing:

[image]

Here is the code I have now:

```
    console.log('Update area');
    console.log('changing area ' + req.params.id_area);
    //console.log(req.body);

    const { errors, isValid } = mapValidators.validateAreaInput(req.body);

    // Check Validation
    if(!isValid){
        return res.status(400).json(errors);
    }

    MappedImage.findById(req.params.id)
    .then(map => {

        // Check to see if area exists
        if (
            map.areas.filter(
            area => area._id.toString() === req.params.id_area
            ).length === 0
        ) {
            return res.status(404).json({ areanotfound: 'Area does not exist' });
        }

        console.log('area exists');

        // get all of the areas from the map...
        var allAreas = map.areas;

        console.log('all areas');
        console.log(allAreas);

        // now get the index of the area we are going to update
        const areaIndex = map.areas.map(item => item._id.toString()).indexOf(req.params.id_area);

        console.log('area index');
        console.log(areaIndex);

        // update the information
        var coords = req.body.coords.split(',');
        const updatedArea = {
            name: req.body.name,
            shape: req.body.shape,
            preFillColor: req.body.preFillColor,
            fillColor: req.body.fillColor,

            coords: coords,
        };

        console.log('updated area');
        console.log(updatedArea);


        // set the updated information in the maps areas
        allAreas[areaIndex] = updatedArea;

        console.log('creating query');
        var query = {"_id": req.params.id, "areas._id": req.params.id_area};
        console.log('query');
        console.log(query);


        var update = {$set: {"areas.$": updatedArea}};
        console.log('update');
        console.log(update);

        var options = {new: true};

        MappedImage.findOneAndUpdate(query, update, options)
        .then(map => res.json(map))
        .catch(err => res.status(404).json({ mapnotfound: err }));

    })
    .catch(err => res.status(404).json({ mapnotfound: 'Map not found while updating area' }));
```

Here is the terminal output:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try setting the `_id` property in the `updatedArea` object with the value of the area that you'd like to update. This would prevent creating a new id while using the `$set` operator. Something like this:

```
// now get the index of the area we are going to update
const areaIndex = map.areas.map(item => item._id.toString()).indexOf(req.params.id_area);

// update the information
var coords = req.body.coords.split(',');
const updatedArea = {
        _id: id_area,
        name: req.body.name,
        shape: req.body.shape,
        coords: coords,
};
...
```

Note that with the above solution you're always setting a new array, which is why new id's are generated.

You could also try updating the specific element in the array using the `$` [operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update-array/):

```
var query = {"_id": req.params.id, "areas._id": id_area}; // this is the MAP id
var update = {$set: {"areas.$": updatedArea}};  // update the area
```

See the screenshots below for an example (executing the commands in the mongodb-shell) where I'm trying to only update the second array element (i.e. with _id `5c5c8db2f904932dd8d4c561`)

[image: Before executing command]

[image: After executing command]

Comment: I guess what I am wondering is why doesn't the id for the map get updated when I make a similar call?  ( I will edit the question to include code for that so you can see what I mean )

Comment: Edited question to show main map update call and put in statement about how perplexing the main id doesn't change

Comment: that works... but it just seems a little too much like a "hack" ... if you get my drift...  there has to be a solid reason for it happening and a way to make it not happen.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/3761628/eol : does the code I wrote make sense?  Can it be done more elegantly?  any other tips or suggestions?

Comment: The thing is you're not actually "updating" the value, but you're setting a new array. That's why it gets a new id. In the example above with `var update = {imageUrl: req.body.imageUrl, name: req.body.name};` you're really just updating values, hence the object-id stays the same. But I think there's another way -> you could also access the array index with the id and perform an actual update of the object, I'll update my answer. I can't test it right now, let me know if that solution works as well :)

Comment: I am trying your approach using the $ operator... where/how do you get "areas._id"  ?  (it's undefined in my code)  same with "areas.$"  ( I think this is getting the schema definition ... but I don't know how to do that )

Comment: @MLissCetrus: My bad, try wrapping it in a string -> I've updated my answer. I tested it and this works (at least directly in the mongodb-shell).

Comment: Thanks for the input... I think I am now down to a react error... see update on question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/3761628/eol - the changes I put in are still updating the areas._id - any other suggestions?